# c++ test to see if double * double will overflow uint64_t

Tags: c++

```
bool multiply_overflow_double(double a,double b)
{
    double v = a * b;
    if (std::isfinite(v))
        return (v >  std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max());
    return true;
}
```

I have been given two doubles I need to check if it will overflow a uint64_t. I did think about doing the traditional way with division but this seems simpler.

What are the obvious problems given that a and b will be greater than 0, vs the traditional way?

Comment: @KillzoneKid I have already checked that elsewhere.

Comment: It's not clear how the function you listed relates to your question.

Comment: There's really no question in your question. What is the problem you have with the code you show?

Comment: What question? A very thorough examination of what's written above fails to produce any specific programming question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I wanted to know if there are edge cases that are not obvious.

Comment: If `v` is negative...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is hazardous with an IEEE754 `double` since not all integers greater than the 53rd power of 2 can be represented exactly, so `a * b` might be truncated to a smaller value than the actual product. Hence your `return` might give you false negatives. Other `double` schemes will suffer similarly.

Note also that `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()` will be converted to a `double` too - for IEEE754 you'll get `18446744073709551616` instead of `18446744073709551615`.

The traditional division check doesn't suffer from these effects.

Comment: It's worth a +1 if you add the traditional check code here, and comment back at me.

Comment: @JonathanMee: It's pretty fiddly, and you shouldn't really do it in floating point. Here's a version for signed types, but trivial to adapt: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow

Comment: Hows the coffee today

Comment: @SombreroChicken: Wonderful, although I might have needed another one had I attempted to write out the division check.